# undefined method in_rendering_context

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6

After updating from rails 5.2 to rails 6. I am getting this error. The issue lies in the render method

```
NoMethodError - undefined method `in_rendering_context' for #<UserPdf:0x000056199a9e1ec0>:
  app/controllers/users_controller.rb:39:in `download_receipt'
  app/controllers/application_controller.rb:345:in `set_current_user'
  app/middleware/skip_trackable.rb:8:in `call'


def download_receipt
  @presenter = UserPresenter.new
  pdf = UserPdf.new(@presenter)
  send_data pdf.render, type: 'application/pdf', filename: @presenter.file_name
end
```

I was going through this articles https://github.com/komposable/komponent/issues/133 but didn't got much help. Anyone else has encountered this issue or any help will be appreciated

This PR: https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/3077cdf921fed35c1e743db5911d7e4b589a684e has change the method internally from in_context to in_rendering_context

Rails - 6.0.3.4

Ruby - 2.7.2

Comment: Which is line number 39? What is `TransactionPdf`?

Comment: TransactionPdf is a presenter where I am storing details of transactions

Comment: Where is line 39?  And what is in `UserPdf`?  The method `in_rendering_context` is being called on your `pdf` object whose code is missing.